# Multithread in a Loop

Tags: c++, c++11

I am presenting an "minimalist example" to try to understand how can i make multi-threading in C++11. So given this example:

```
std::thread t[total_threads];
for(int i = 0; i<total_threads; i++){
   t[i]= std::thread(&thread_function_1, random1, parameters1);
   t[i].join();
   t[i]= std::thread(&thread_function_2, random2, parameters2);
   t[i].join();
   t[i]= std::thread(&thread_function_2, random3, parameters3);
   t[i].join();
}
```

Obviously if I try to debugg this code I will have *abortion errors.* Since is not possible to use the same thread twice (I guess). One possible solution is to create an array with "millions" of threads to make it happen (and iterate between them). But I guess it is a bad solution. How can I make this efficiently, since I can not use the same thread twice?

Comment: First there is no actual multithreading happening in your code. Second there is nothing wrong with reusing an std::thread. The code you are showing and the problem you have don't match.

Comment: Why do you join just after creating a thread ? There will not be multithreading at this stage.

Comment: @nwp I want to achieve that. But I am in the frist steps.

Comment: Normally you have two Loops: in the first Loop you create all the threads, in the second Loop you join all threads

Comment: What do you mean by _if I try to debug this code I will have abortion errors_? If you start the debugger the program crashes with an unhandled exception?

Comment: It's not obvious at all that you will have abortion errors. Why do you think that you would get errors? Did you get errors? Were there error messages?

Comment: ThreadPool      .    ..

Comment: logics is wrong: what about googling "thread tutorial c++11"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join()` means to block program execution until the specified thread has returned. Therefore at best you need to do something more like this..

```
// Spawn threads
std::thread t[total_threads];
for(int i = 0; i<total_threads; i++){
   t[i]= std::thread(&thread_function[i], random[i], parameters[i]);
}

// Wait for threads, which are running concurrently, to finish
for(int i = 0; i<total_threads; i++){
   t[i].join();
}
```

That said, there is a lot of work to multi-threading which includes understanding how the various threads you are spawning access data to ensure they aren't all touching the same data. Also there is a good chance that your program is not structured well for multi-threading if each of these threads is calling a different function. Often times when you are spawning a set number of threads all at once you are trying to break up the processing of a data set amongst threads, each of which has to be processed in a similar fashion (ie same function)

Answer (score -1):

If you try to debug this code, there should be no abort errors, unless you're getting some because of what `thread_function_1` et al do.

It is safe to reuse a thread object after you joined it.

To achieve real multithreading, you need to start several threads and let them run, joining only when they are done, for which purpose you need to use some synchronization, say, condition variables.